# Parametric to non parametric conversion of a line in 3d

Tags: linear-algebra

I can't for the life of me figure out how to convert this parametric equation to a non parametric equation for a line in 3D. Our lecture notes didn't cover it and I feel like it should be simple but whenever I try to figure it out I end up with nothing. Can someone try to explain how this can be done? The question is:
Convert the parametric equation:
(x, y, z) = (2, −1, −2) + t(3, 1, 2)
to a nonparametric equation.

I know that you're probably meant to come up with the equations for x, y and z:

x= 2 + 3t

y = -1 + t

z = -2 + 2t

but I'm not sure what to do with these

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: _HINT_: rewrite the three equations for $xyz$ so that $t$ is all on its own. Then equate them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A non-parametric representation of a line in 3D won't be a *single equation* but rather *a system of (two) equations* in the Cartesian coordinates $x$, $y$ and $z$.

As the name suggests, you should try to eliminate the parameter by first solving for $t$:
$$\left\{ \begin{array}{rcl}
x &=& 2 + 3t \\
y &=& -1 + t \\
z &=& -2 + 2t
\end{array} \right. \; (t \in \mathbb{R}) \quad\Rightarrow\quad
\left\{ \begin{array}{rcl}
t &=& \frac{x-2}{3} \\
t &=& y+1 \\
t &=& \frac{z+2}{2}
\end{array} \right. \; (t \in \mathbb{R})$$
and now equating these three expressions for $t$.

---

In general (if $v_i \ne 0$ for $i=1,2,3$), you'd have:
$$\left\{ \begin{array}{rcl}
x &=& a_1 + v_1t \\
y &=& a_2 + v_2t \\
z &=& a_3 + v_3t
\end{array} \right. \; (t \in \mathbb{R}) \quad\Rightarrow\quad
\left\{ \begin{array}{rcl}
t &=& \frac{x-a_1}{v_1} \\
t &=& \frac{y-a_2}{v_2} \\
t &=& \frac{z-a_3}{v_3}
\end{array} \right. \; (t \in \mathbb{R})$$
This leads to the following standard form:
$$\color{blue}{\frac{x-a_1}{v_1} = \frac{y-a_2}{v_2} = \frac{z-a_3}{v_3}}$$

Note: this will not always be possible (one or more of the $v_i$'s might be $0$), but then you can still obtain a system of two equations by elimination of the parameter through substitution.

Comment: It took me a bit longer to typeset this, but this is essentially what Parcly Taxel suggests in his comment.

Comment: Okay thank you, I understand all of this I think, once I have it in that standard form, is that the final form? I ask because when I've looked back at our lecture notes the non parametric form is listed as ax + by + cz = d, but I'm not seeing that form anywhere else that I search, only the standard form you've mentioned. Thanks again!

Comment: The equation $ax + by + cz = d$ represents a *plane* (in 3D), not a line. A line would be the system of two such equations (i.e. the intersection of two planes), a form you can get from the (blue) standard form by explicitly writing it as a system of two equations; e.g.
$$\left\{ \begin{array}{rcl}
\frac{x-a_1}{v_1} = \frac{y-a_2}{v_2} \\
\frac{y-a_2}{v_2} = \frac{z-a_3}{v_3}
\end{array} \right.$$

Comment: Okay that makes a lot of sense actually, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You're welcome!